# How can I number subtheorems hierachically?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I want to create two hierarchy levels of theorems. The goal is to have something like this:

```
Research Question 1: bla bla
Research Question 2: bla bla
```

And then in another section of the article, I would like to do something like this:

```
Research Question 1.1 bla bla
Research Question 1.2 bla bla

Research Question 2.1 bla bla
Research Question 2.2 bla bla
```

I used the following code:

```
\newtheorem{researchquestion}{Research Question}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subresearchquestion}[1]{%
  \def\subtheoremcounter{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\theparentnumber{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \setcounter{parentnumber}{\value{#1}}%
  \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{\theparentnumber.\Alph{#1}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{\subtheoremcounter}{\value{parentnumber}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{parentnumber}
```

However, the result is not exactly how it should look like:
  Research Question 1: bla bla
    Research Question 2: bla bla

And then in another section of the article, I would like to do something like this:

```
Research Question 3.1 bla bla
Research Question 3.2 bla bla

Research Question 4.1 bla bla
Research Question 4.2 bla bla
```

How can I achieve that the subtheorems are really subtheorems? I tried this approach: [How to number subtheorems hierarchically?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39769/how-to-number-subtheorems-hierarchically) but the problem then is that the theorem numbering is influenced by the section numbering. I want this two things have independently.

Comment: It's not really clear: the questions you number 1.1 and 1.2 should refer to the question numbered 1, while 3.1 has nothing to do with a question 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See also [Remove chapter number from theorem number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16282/remove-chapter-number-from-theorem-number?rq=1)

```
\documentclass{article}   

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{subtheorem}{Sub-Theorem}[theorem]

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}
\renewcommand{\thesubtheorem}{\arabic{theorem}.\arabic{subtheorem}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem} 
 Yada yada yada. 
\end{theorem}   

\begin{subtheorem}   
  Yada yada yada.
\end{subtheorem}

\begin{subtheorem}   
  Yada yada yada.
\end{subtheorem}

\begin{theorem} 
 Yada yada yada. 
\end{theorem}   

\begin{subtheorem}   
  Yada yada yada.
\end{subtheorem}

\begin{subtheorem}   
  Yada yada yada.
\end{subtheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]